# XCode App randomly crashing - message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting the following error on my app when it randomly crashes during testing.

[image]

### The logs show the following:

[image]

Is there any way possible I can track why this error is apprearing? I'll be super grateful.

Best.

Comment: There is a lots of similar questions on stackoverflow, please search before asking.

Comment: Did you enable Zombie Objects in your scheme? It helps a lot:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994549/enable-and-debug-zombie-objects-in-ios-using-xcode-5-1-1

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Breakpoint Navigator.  Click the plus sign on the bottom left.  Add exception breakpoint. It will break right before the weird error you are seeing :)

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks a lot for your assistance. I am very ashamed to ask, but I am struggling to find the plus sign in the Breakpoint Navigator. May be I've been unable to find the Breakpoint Navigator. I apologize for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

You know the pane on the left that shows your files? At the top of it there are 7 buttons or so, and one is shaped like a breakpoint. That's the navigator.