# App crashing when trying to setValue in NSMuableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

My app is crashing when I try to set value in `NSMutableDictionary`.

Here is the code below which demostrate the crash, I am not able to find out any crash log also in the console.

```
NSArray *b =[[a objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"value"];
NSMutableDictionary *b1 =[b objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *str = self.tes;
[b1 setValue:str forKey:@"value"];
```

Please help me regarding this.

b1 Dictionary log

```
{
    question = "vale";
    type = a;
}
```

Comment: what is in b1 dictionary add Log with your question.

Comment: i have added the log in the question

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *b1 = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[b objectAtIndex:0]]; Try this

Comment: Please try as @jogshardik said. (Y)

Comment: its is using common memory location for accessing data and updating the values in the same memory location. we cannot alloc init the dictionary

Comment: [b1 setValue:"yourvalue" forKey:"question"] @GauravParmar because there is no key like value !!!

Comment: are you sure that b1 is a dictionary and not just a JSON dict

Comment: b1 doesn't contain key = value that's why it is crashing

Comment: What message does the crash print to debugger? Try logging `b1.class` to see whether it is really mutable.

Comment: Yes i have check that its mutable. @iMartin

Comment: So what is the error message? The reason of the crash? Unrecognized selector? Undefined key? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? There must be something.

Comment: Ouch, that sounds like the problem is not in this code. Try enabling Zombies in Scheme.

Answer (score 4):

`setValue:forKey:` is part of the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol, which among other things, lets you access object properties from the likes of Interface Builder. `setValue:forKey:` is implemented in classes other than NSDictionary.

`setObject:forKey:` is `NSMutableDictionary`'s reason to exist. Its signature happens to be quite similar to `setValue:forKey:`, but is more generic (e.g. any key type).

So in your case just replace all `setValue:forKey` with `setObject:forKey` and `valueForKey:` with `objectForKey:`

--

[Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

Comment: Using `setValue:forKey:` is actualy safer, because it handles `nil` values by removing the key. On the other side, `setObject:forKey:` would throw exception and probably crash the app.

Comment: I prefer to handle `nil` values rather than collect a strange bugs :)

Comment: What bugs? It’s defined and documented behavior of `NSMutableDictionary`. Also makes sense: if you set `nil` for `@"key"`, then getting value for `@"key"` should be `nil` (non-existent).

Answer (score 0):

So you said you are getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash. Try turning on *Zombies* in Xcode’s Scheme editor. See [Enable and Debug Zombie objects in iOS using Xcode 5.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994549/enable-and-debug-zombie-objects-in-ios-using-xcode-5-1-1). That question explains how to use it, but you don’t need to run Instruments as mentioned there.

Then just run the app and Xcode will show you the reason of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Don’t forget to turn Zombies **off** after you don’t need it.

The name *Zombie* comes from the fact that under this mode all deallocated objects will be marked and will be kept as special regions of memory (not live, not dead, zombies). Once your code attempts to use such deallocated object, Xcode will notice and print helpful message.

Comment: enabling zoombie also not provided any solution to me.. :(

Comment: i think the issue is with memory allocation in the ios. can you check with that?