# Cordova app crash log reason

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I got this from the crash log of the device from Xcode. I have a feeling that this might be due to **cc.fovea.cordova.purchase** plugin, but I don't understand these crash log.

```
Incident Identifier: 672AADC3-2D8A-4490-B176-9A1ED42984E7
CrashReporter Key:   eb135d2d39b9bf52857cccf0b01d7673befa81e3
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             WeatherSpork [16501]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E3BE110D-6892-42CE-8679-A4E6FBF5E323/WeatherSpork.app/WeatherSpork
Identifier:          net.buser.weatherspork
Version:             0.17.05.17.79 (0.9.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           net.buser.weatherspork [3944]


Date/Time:           2017-05-19 18:03:31.7408 +0530
Launch Time:         2017-05-19 17:37:50.5943 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2.1 (14D27)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000544746570
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018e8b2f70 objc_msgSend + 16
1   StoreKit                        0x000000019cb1abf0 __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 52
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ecf21fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ecf21bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ecf6d68 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe16810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe143fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fd422b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
8   GraphicsServices                0x00000001917f6198 GSEventRunModal + 180
9   UIKit                           0x0000000195d897fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
10  UIKit                           0x0000000195d84534 UIApplicationMain + 208
11  WeatherSpork                    0x00000001000c3f80 0x1000bc000 + 32640
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018ed255b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee19188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee18ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe165d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe141ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fd422b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000019087f26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000019089fdd0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x00000001966fdc38 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000019097ce68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd850 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd760 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad94 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee19188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee18ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe165d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe141ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fd422b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000190547a70 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6   Foundation                      0x000000019097ce68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd850 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd760 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad94 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee37314 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018ed5525c nanosleep + 212
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018e865994 std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) + 80
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000194645368 bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 272
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000194645134 bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 80
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001946464f8 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 92
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000194646424 std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() + 0
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001946466d4 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd850 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd760 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad94 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  JIT Worklist Worker Thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee36e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefc9c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018e8253ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019462ed64 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 2132
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000194406a5c JSC::JITWorklist::runThread() + 192
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000194406eac WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<JSC::JITWorklist::Plan>, 32ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>::expandCapacity(unsigned long, WTF::RefPtr<JSC::JITWorklist::Plan>*) + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193d7700c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193d76f1c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd850 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd760 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad94 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  WTF Parallel Helper Thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee36e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefc9c0 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018e8253ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019462ed64 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 2132
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019462e2e8 WTF::ParallelHelperPool::waitForClientWithTask(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&) + 288
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019462e088 WTF::ParallelHelperPool::helperThreadBody() + 76
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193d7700c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193d76f1c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd850 _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd760 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad94 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  GAIThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee19188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee18ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe165d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fe141ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fd422b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000019087f26c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001908d3aa0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   WeatherSpork                    0x0000000100116a0c 0x1000bc000 + 371212
8   Foundation                      0x000000019097ce68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd850 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefd760 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad94 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee37a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefb344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad8c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee37a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefb344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad8c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee37a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefb344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad8c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee19188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ee18ff8 mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ecf21a0 _dispatch_send_wakeup_runloop_thread + 68
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ecfff44 _dispatch_runloop_queue_poke + 256
4   StoreKit                        0x000000019cb1abac -[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:] + 100
5   StoreKit                        0x000000019cb1af94 __36-[SKProductsRequest _sendXPCMessage]_block_invoke + 52
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018ef3afcc _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 80
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018ef3af3c _xpc_connection_call_reply + 40
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ecf21bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ed00a4c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 732
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ed0234c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ed020ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefb2a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad8c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018eefad88 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000174032240   x1: 0x000000019684bab9   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0xfffffff0001fc088
    x4: 0x0000000000002403   x5: 0x00000000ffffffff   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001b4666000   x9: 0x0000000000000020  x10: 0x000000012dd112c0  x11: 0x000000100000001f
   x12: 0x000000012dd11330  x13: 0x6369766544746567  x14: 0x0000000008000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000544746560  x17: 0x000000019cb1d25c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000170252270
   x20: 0x000000017027b040  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000014
   x24: 0x00000001b5596d20  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0xffffffffffffffff  x27: 0x000000017027b040
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016fd42bf0   lr: 0x000000019cb1abf0
    sp: 0x000000016fd42bc0   pc: 0x000000018e8b2f70 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images:
0x1000bc000 - 0x1001c3fff WeatherSpork arm64  <2c0e99756d4b3e489c79190cbf65b326> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E3BE110D-6892-42CE-8679-A4E6FBF5E323/WeatherSpork.app/WeatherSpork
0x100308000 - 0x100337fff dyld arm64  <f54ed85a94253887886a8028e20ed8ba> /usr/lib/dyld
0x18e81c000 - 0x18e81dfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <1b4d75209f4a37969a9575de48d48668> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x18e81e000 - 0x18e873fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <b2db8b1d09283b7bafe1b2933adc5dfd> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x18e874000 - 0x18e894fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <e3419bbaface31b5970c6c8d430be26d> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x18e898000 - 0x18ec71fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <538f809dcd7c35ceb59d99802248f045> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x18ec72000 - 0x18ec76fff libcache.dylib arm64  <f09cab6893c631218f817e61b3d77fcb> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x18ec77000 - 0x18ec82fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <e071643355cd3f67bae19045c7f9f340> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18ec83000 - 0x18ec86fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <8209cb28df5d3b48894899019fcbb344> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x18ec87000 - 0x18ec8efff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <567f33ef4d8f3e48a5afac933ccd389f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x18ec8f000 - 0x18ecf0fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <056a6c201d3d3696b59f0b264ba9b972> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x18ecf1000 - 0x18ed20fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <fb1d0baf642337d1bea0af309586df97> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x18ed21000 - 0x18ed25fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <db54f120486a3710a684ce8bb1cb9d71> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x18ed26000 - 0x18ed26fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <ceb57f62c49e38d8a8d33309db668bd3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x18ed27000 - 0x18ed2cfff libmacho.dylib arm64  <20627f9f062c3ee8873e3ab3bc3fda8c> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x18ed2d000 - 0x18ed2efff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <43110ffd953537e28981c6dead2c0b1f> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18ed2f000 - 0x18ed46fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <e52a49b27e963d2bb90332a5b0895f8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x18ed47000 - 0x18ed47fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <480fe954b3f63f16af8acfd6dc34e2da> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x18ed48000 - 0x18edc6fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <8a5a190d70563f3c8d4ce16cab74f599> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18edc7000 - 0x18edcbfff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <7628c33e4c383a78b0e33cf403e6f019> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x18edcc000 - 0x18edd1fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <9de64e7545ab359fb9cefc695aa510f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x18edd2000 - 0x18edd3fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <e61211f8f4c9399595fbd921e8589a8b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18edd4000 - 0x18edecfff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <14fa1ba4b14b338181c2ef87b214695e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x18eded000 - 0x18edf3fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <7d745bdfb72e3119bad43c36f60a5a8a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x18edf4000 - 0x18ee17fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <6546bc8b4fa23df898bf2471e801d50b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x18ee18000 - 0x18ee3cfff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <1baa3f5629c43467879d4cf463a20b06> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x18ee3d000 - 0x18ee69fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <ba786894a7213d37baa99aafc0ee5493> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x18ee6a000 - 0x18ee85fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <c57ecb4ada5c3930a580b3d07583058a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x18ee86000 - 0x18eeddfff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <efa018a4cb4936e3b77b9194d390efc4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x18eede000 - 0x18eee7fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <34c2d9c2986f32dd996e4e439d94c9c5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x18eee8000 - 0x18eef2fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <605beaf21db73cc3ae98a65e8c11f7d0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x18eef3000 - 0x18eef9fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <518e18adfdfc316e9b4d519f6e4b6a47> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x18eefa000 - 0x18ef03fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <258dc0c51499393bba7ba3e83dc5bfbb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x18ef04000 - 0x18ef07fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <0db039dc34223f498b11aed09cfce7f2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x18ef08000 - 0x18ef0ffff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <832499573c1730b48f6ff8e7c06fae15> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x18ef10000 - 0x18ef2efff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <c5a7bdd0667a3b2a9cb458d3854d8f90> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x18ef2f000 - 0x18ef34fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <7a7545249f7d3a69a162acb73ec4f17a> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x18ef35000 - 0x18ef35fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <21d158555a6233b19c53df16cafb6974> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x18ef36000 - 0x18ef5cfff libxpc.dylib arm64  <8f1330e254b83bd3a973af6933b91836> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x18ef5d000 - 0x18f177fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <35fc5fa2aab8326897081ab8416c497c> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x18f178000 - 0x18f188fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <b3ab59ff330f3225a53b4e8e95440d77> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x18fd39000 - 0x1900bdfff CoreFoundation arm64  <dd9791d198ef32eea1335b8ebc9b3d55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1900be000 - 0x1900cefff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <788093e9b6b738cea7045bfec4bef1d8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1900cf000 - 0x1900cffff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <3bcefd094fa83b26807a1c6c92933cd2> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1900d0000 - 0x19014bfff IOKit arm64  <e0a6f4f0810b3f75813eda2afebd591c> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x19014c000 - 0x19016cfff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <1e9e78da74143c54bb1e50aa7e285a0f> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x19016d000 - 0x190257fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <b3fc55542fe33491877c661cf410b164> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x190258000 - 0x1902e6fff Security arm64  <88e5d6eb0de13ff6b7904f1b0e43a88e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1902e7000 - 0x190351fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <d907035d1ff936e5986035f50a77f5d3> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x190352000 - 0x190467fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <87863a80836a3d659e5485f5029c3ed4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x190468000 - 0x190801fff CFNetwork arm64  <5fc8f0f909a0314aa15c7853c5c8fea3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x190802000 - 0x190812fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <0d14fa7337f43079bad2a4cfc6d66b70> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x190813000 - 0x19082bfff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <b90cea0595ff3f8599d9788e1d2cb454> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x19082c000 - 0x190846fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <ac663b865b6b38429a40878701aa484a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x190847000 - 0x190870fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <eca0acf41ac83d0a92230eb5b19c39c6> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x190871000 - 0x190872fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <a74f4f8a2d533e1f926044f052cc5b7d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x190873000 - 0x190b41fff Foundation arm64  <7d40355e685036cc803455e5cbf6245f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x190b42000 - 0x190beefff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <fa29c2ad87a73ccea2885d9182faee53> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x190bef000 - 0x190f31fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <6df40b0afcbb35a48d63e2fa8ec03b1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x190f32000 - 0x1911d4fff vImage arm64  <8b797590cf983693b4c3b6b83dc4ba29> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1911d5000 - 0x1911f7fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <5bcbb491c0a03816a7634797852c21ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1911f8000 - 0x19120cfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <1adeb99764f63e9e8ef1225bb7a5120d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x19120d000 - 0x19121efff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <515a7b8f5c433b709c1f6d205b9a73d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x19121f000 - 0x191297fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <80294f738c053c4991fa3ab4e867218e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x191298000 - 0x191298fff vecLib arm64  <15dc1eafe1f8377d9cab3ba5c7e488be> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x191299000 - 0x191299fff Accelerate arm64  <32a527bb13a63e37bf50c725b008e9d5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x19129a000 - 0x1917e9fff CoreGraphics arm64  <bd7ec9e2358f3670aef8e025df08d2e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1917ea000 - 0x1917fefff GraphicsServices arm64  <7c0dd118a4bc37dc8fab6449abde7ff9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1917ff000 - 0x19184afff AppSupport arm64  <bdaad3a71677315bb126c4a73a1bcb9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x19184b000 - 0x19196efff MobileCoreServices arm64  <e035420bfabe3f28bc6eef0a144ac1d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x19196f000 - 0x1919c7fff BaseBoard arm64  <210cb4a9a0073c7b9e0b3d437cc1aa4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x1919c8000 - 0x1919d3fff AssertionServices arm64  <7ca242e983fd3c0f805d51fca8a4c46a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1919d4000 - 0x191a00fff BackBoardServices arm64  <c333604ae8123e3cbb46fe26f233beb9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x191a05000 - 0x191a54fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <00b3c2ff89f53d3dba0069b6bb5a56bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x191a58000 - 0x191a8bfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <9a9b5eba8bf63364861083f874ff612a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x191a8c000 - 0x191aa0fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <a78d40cc257231978e752c5a81cd1356> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x191aa1000 - 0x191aa9fff IOSurface arm64  <9a22349e905539a0a1598af6d7fe9cc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x191aaa000 - 0x191ab5fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <ab36b2ace988302c89207cb290ff4a76> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x191ab6000 - 0x191accfff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <3bffb6a60faf3560acd6f4bc832b66ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x191acd000 - 0x191acffff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <7b7c2b7ea506374cb3902b7408d5d4bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x191ad0000 - 0x191b10fff AppleJPEG arm64  <b2fd4ef37aaf38f58311e33ea1683082> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x191b11000 - 0x1920a3fff ImageIO arm64  <f5ddfe623d4f3a338ae75c666ea10815> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1920a4000 - 0x1920aafff TCC arm64  <c9f168508185369591dfcd1c1cf9b6a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x1920ab000 - 0x1920affff AggregateDictionary arm64  <9eeea99a19a83db18b28e9010b6c390b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1920b0000 - 0x1920bcfff PowerLog arm64  <113534d73def3d7ab109bcbc4d965d8e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1920bd000 - 0x192125fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <d31ff5ec574d338e8d02155963d17950> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x192126000 - 0x192138fff CommonUtilities arm64  <486d816afdc431aaa2ef67b229cf4e96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x192139000 - 0x19214dfff libcompression.dylib arm64  <c764915fa0ec384f8a1759e63235b5a9> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x19214e000 - 0x1923ecfff CoreData arm64  <980c0f8663a0330d8b5fb541c22e7b66> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1923ed000 - 0x1923f2fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <3a28c232b17430839305f9d17745e247> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1923f3000 - 0x1923f8fff IOAccelerator arm64  <f4d5cd421bd03a52b40c991fd1c73806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x1923f9000 - 0x1923fafff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <7110757134ea3599b3d739db2ea6f48a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1923fb000 - 0x1923fefff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <2147b40a3d713d53b221e8f40ca5ac7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1923ff000 - 0x192442fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <c2e2de9ee34236558c89d7fe9bc0116c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x192443000 - 0x19244dfff libGFXShared.dylib arm64
```

....
....
.....
    EOF

It is a Cordova app with following plugins installed:

```
<plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" spec="^6.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Need geolocation to track sun and moon position." />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="git+https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git#ba242fc" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.1.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Exception Type **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)** represented that we are accessing a released object

Looks like an object was deallocated yet the code assumed it was valid.

Try **Zombies** in Instruments . it will help to find where you sent message to released object so this crash happens.

[How to use zombies in xcode ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994549/enable-and-debug-zombie-objects-in-ios-using-xcode-5-1-1)