# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20) When subView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, exc-bad-access, quickblox

I got a strange error. `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)`
When a View subView on another view.

Both v`iew object not nil.`

How do I solve this issue.

**Edit:**
I am implementing a video chat code with VOIP.

When an incoming call comes and after accept the call. I need to display a screen.
This screen is showing fine and other UIElements button etc.. (including button functionalities) everything is working as expected for audio calls.

But, in video call after receive the remote user video I am trying to subView to a view . I could view the remote user screen for  a second. suddenly get crashed (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)).

```
func session(_ session: QBRTCBaseSession, receivedRemoteVideoTrack videoTrack: QBRTCVideoTrack, fromUser userID: NSNumber) {

  if (session as! QBRTCSession).id == self.session?.id {

      let remoteView :QBRTCRemoteVideoView = QBRTCRemoteVideoView()
      remoteView.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect.rawValue
      remoteView.clipsToBounds = true
      remoteView.setVideoTrack(videoTrack)
      remoteView.tag = userID.intValue

      var frame = self.mainVideoView.bounds
      frame.origin.y = 0
      remoteView.frame = frame

      self.view.addSubview(remoteView)
     }
}
```

Where `receivedRemoteVideoTrack` function is a delegate method for the remote video.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something is `nil`; You need to edit your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: @Paulw11: I have edited the question.

Comment: Is this a valid forced cast: `(session as! QBRTCSession)`?

Comment: @staticVoidMan: session type is 'QBRTCSession'. Also this condition is succeeded and View the video for a second.

Comment: Which lines does the crash occur on?  Set an exception breakpoint

Comment: if I comment 'self.view.addSubview(remoteView)' not crashing. But, I could view the remote video for a second (ie, first frame is loaded.).

Comment: @Paulw11: same error

Comment: Turn on Zombies?

Comment: I think enable Zombies from Edit scheme right? After enalble, How do I get the error reason

Comment: Still the proble exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `Metal` only available with `A7` processors or higher. I can suggest you force `OpenGLES` drawings instead of `Metal`, for now, just do this:

```
QBRTCRemoteVideoView.preferMetal = NO
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Working fine. :)

Comment: There is a strange behaviour, some times this line crashes, QBRTCRemoteVideoView.preferMetal = NO. Woking fine without this. (same device)